# How to use a saved ML model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset, classification

I have the following code for training and then saving the model (in three different ways):

```
    
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', ';')
df = df.drop(labels=['first label', 'second label', 'third label'], axis=1)

X = df['post'].values
y = df['final'].values


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_test, y_test, test_size=0.5)

MODEL_NAME = 'bert-large-uncased'
t = text.Transformer(MODEL_NAME)
train = t.preprocess_train(X_train, y_train, verbose=True)
val = t.preprocess_test(X_val, y_val, verbose=True)
test = t.preprocess_test(X_test, y_test, verbose=True)
model = t.get_classifier()

f1 = train_model(model, train, val, test, lr=1.7e-5, batch_size=7)

model.save('mymodel.tf', save_format='tf')
model.save_weights("myweights.h5")
tf.saved_model.save(model, 'my_saved_model')
```

And now I'm trying to use the saved model (I'm trying to use the `.tf` one but I don't know which is better to use) to further analyze a dataset in the following way:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', delimiter=';')

df = df.drop(['first label', 'second label', 'third label'], axis=1)

X = df['post'].values

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('mymodel.tf')

prediction = model.predict(X[:1])[0][0]

print(prediction)
```

But I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    prediction = model.predict(X[:1])[0][0]
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: in user code:

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'tf_bert_for_sequence_classification_1' (type TFBertForSequenceClassification).

    Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (11 total):
        * <tf.Tensor 'input_ids:0' shape=(None,) dtype=string>
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}

     Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):

    Option 1:
      Positional arguments (11 total):
        * {'attention_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids_attention_mask'),
     'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids_input_ids'),
     'token_type_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids_token_type_ids')}
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * None
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}
```

How can I correctly use the saved model (in any of the three format) to analyze a dataset, now that it's saved?

Thanks!

Comment: there is a mismatch between the expected input format of the loaded model and the input data you are trying to predict on. The loaded model expects specific input tensor shapes and data types, but the input data you are passing in does not match those expectations.

Comment: Thank you. So how can I achieve the prediction? You can see how I train and save the model (three different saving). How can I then load the model and dataset?